# How to run a custom function in R multiple times using a data frame to get the argument for each run

Tags: r, function, arguments, mapply

I wrote a function to output all values for a specified categorical variable into an output data frame. I'm more used to using call execute in SAS. This works if I manually write out the function with the variable name, but it does not if I try to use mapply. I'm not very experienced (yet) using apply, lapply, mapply, etc, but I have a lot of values I want to run this on (so would like to use a dataframe to specify the function arguments).

Does anyone have any suggestions? REPREX below:

This works (outputs a table listing all variables and all values associated with each one):

```
a<-data.frame(var1=c("one","two","three"),var2=c("ants","moths","cows"),var3=c("Sam","Sally","Jugdish")) 
b<-data.frame(VNAME=c("var1","var2","var3"))
getvals<-function(varb){
  temp<-a %>% mutate(VNAME=quo_name(enquo(varb))) %>% mutate(VALUE={{varb}}) %>% select(c(VNAME,VALUE)) %>% distinct()
  Values<-bind_rows(Values,temp)
  Values<-Values %>% filter(VNAME != 'delete' & !is.na(VALUE))
  Values<<-Values
}
Values<-data.frame(VNAME='delete')
getvals(var1)
getvals(var2)
getvals(var3)
```

But this does not - in fact it just outputs a table listing the variables in both columns)

```
a<-data.frame(var1=c("one","two","three"),var2=c("ants","moths","cows"),var3=c("Sam","Sally","Jugdish")) 
b<-data.frame(VNAME=c("var1","var2","var3"))
getvals<-function(varb){
  temp<-a %>% mutate(VNAME=quo_name(enquo(varb))) %>% mutate(VALUE={{varb}}) %>% select(c(VNAME,VALUE)) %>% distinct()
  Values<-bind_rows(Values,temp)
  Values<-Values %>% filter(VNAME != 'delete' & !is.na(VALUE))
  Values<<-Values
}
Values<-data.frame(VNAME='delete')
mapply(getvals,b$VNAME)
```

Thank you!

I tried using apply and lapply, but got the same results.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do, apart from this particular method?

Comment: You might consider `tidyr::pivot_longer(a, everything())` to do in one step what your function does for all the variables in a. Is the idea you want to combine the variables from multiple tables?

Comment: As Jon points out there is a simpler solution. But if you insitst: your function `getvals` expects unquoted names, not character strings. Try with `mapply(getvals, syms(b$VNAME))`

Comment: Agree with @JonSpring about this particular problem. To answer your question, though, the [`purrr::pmap()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) family can iterate over arguments passed as dataframe rows. In the documentation, look at the examples starting at "`# Vectorizing a function over multiple arguments.`"

Answer (score 2):

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(a, everything())
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  name  value  
  <chr> <chr>  
1 var1  one    
2 var2  ants   
3 var3  Sam    
4 var1  two    
5 var2  moths  
6 var3  Sally  
7 var1  three  
8 var2  cows   
9 var3  Jugdish
```

Or if you just want certain variables included:

```
include <- c("var1", "var3")
tidyr::pivot_longer(dplyr::select(a, include), everything())

# A tibble: 6 × 2
  name  value  
  <chr> <chr>  
1 var1  one    
2 var3  Sam    
3 var1  two    
4 var3  Sally  
5 var1  three  
6 var3  Jugdish
```

Or as a function for the same output:

```
extract_vars <- function(df, cols) {
  tidyr::pivot_longer(dplyr::select(df, cols), everything())
}

extract_vars(a, include)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The commented answer using `mapply(getvals, syms(b$VNAME))` Actually works really well. In my actual application, it is a reduced list (but still a long list) of variables as opposed to all variables in the dataframe. Also, there have been other times when I wanted to write a function and specify arguments, so this will more generally helpful.